# How to replace some cells number of .csv file if specific lines found in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, centos, data-science, centos7

Lets say I have the following file.csv file content

```
"US","BANANA","123","100","0.5","ok"
"US","APPLE","456","201","0.1", "no"
"US","PIE","789","109","0.8","yes"
"US","APPLE","245","201","0.4","no"
```

I want to search all lines that have APPLE and 201, and then replace the column 5 values to 0. So, my output would look like

```
"US","BANANA","123","100","0.5","ok"
"US","APPLE","456","201","0", "no"
"US","PIE","789","109","0.8","yes"
"US","APPLE","245","201","0","no"
```

I can do grep search

```
grep "APPLE" file.csv | grep 201
```

to find out the lines. But could not figure out how to modify column 5 values of these lines in the original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk -F, '$2=="\"APPLE\"" { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i=="\"201\"") { gsub($5,"\""substr($5,2,length($5)-1)*1.10"\"",$5) } } }1' file.csv
```

Set the field delimiter to , and then when the second field is equal to APPLE in quotes, loop through each field and check if it is equal to 201 in quotes. If it is, replace the 5th field with 0 in quotes using Awk's gsub function. Print each line, changed or otherwise with short-hand 1

Comment: It works. How to change 5th column by a percentage?. For example, rather than using value 0, I want to increase 5th column's value by 10%.

Comment: Try the amended solution

Comment: For some reasons, it is giving me zero (0) in 5th column which should be 0.11 and 0.44

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to take account of the speech marks when trying to increase by 10%. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Would you please explain what "\""substr($5,2,length($5)-1) this part does?

Comment: It's stripping out the quotation marks. The substr function is taking the 5th field and then reading from the second character to the second but last.

Comment: If the solution meets your needs, please take the time to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Greatly appreciate you.